# Binding a jquery value to a specific DIVs height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, skrollr

Sorry, I'm a jquery/js apprentice. I have a jquery sticky nav setup with skrollr set to "stick" at a top offset of 590px.  This seemed okay but I came to find I need that offset to be unique on some pages and instead of having to manually apply the unique offset I wanted to know if I can bind the offset value to a specific DIVs height?  This would help make things easier to manage in the future.

Here is my codez:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  var stickyNavTop = $('#navmenu').offset().top+590;  
  var stickyNav = function(){  
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();    
    if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {   
      $('#navmenu').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('#navmenu').removeClass('sticky');
    }};  
  stickyNav();  
  $(window).scroll(function() {  
    stickyNav();  
  });
});
```

The DIV in question with the height value I need to bind it to has a class of .custom-hero-background

It has a global height applied of 600px but on some pages I override this with unique heights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this in your script, outside of all the other functions, except for `$(document).ready(function(`

```
var theHeight = $('.custom-hero-background').height();
```

and then instead of having a fixed +590 for the offeset, just do + theHeight. If you need it to be 10 pixels less than theHeight, just do theHeight - 10

```
var stickyNavTop = $('#navmenu').offset().top+theHeight;
```